# What are the runtime performance implications of using typed versus untyped F# code quotations?

Tags: .net, f#

I am using `F# Code Quotations` for the purpose of producing an executable .NET library via either `LINQ expression trees` or `FSharp.Compiler.Services`.

I can author/create *most* of the AST needed using typed quotations but am struggling with a particular area as the expression could resolve to multiple types - hence am considering untyped code quotations.

I appreciate from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10640978/when-to-favor-untyped-over-typed-quotations-in-f) the advantages of typed expressions from a safety point of view but my main concern at this point is runtime performance.

1. Is it a meta-programming "code smell" if your expression could resolve to multiple types?
2. Will it make any difference to runtime performance (in .NET) if I use typed versus untyped quotations/expressions

Comment: As with most questions regarding performance: *it depends*. Have you tried to measure the difference?

Comment: In one (of many potential) applications of my testing I wasn't seeing a difference in performance - this *surprised* me. My question is: should I be surprised? If untyped expressions can figure out their types at generation/compile time then perhaps performance would be equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're comparing just untyped and typed F# quotations (that is, the `Expr` and `Expr<'T>` types), then there won't be any real difference. The advantage of typed quotations is that they can (partly) check at compile time that you are constructing a correct quotation, but the underlying representation is actually exactly the same.

If you look at the [definition of `Expr<'T>` in the source code](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/quotations.fs#L288), you can see that it is actually just a lightweight wrapper over `Expr` (which has an additional type parameter, but otherwise represents exactly the same thing).

If you are interested in compiling code more generally then here are a few points:

- F# quotations translate to LINQ Expression trees and so there is an additional step. Also, this is generating slower code than the F# compiler.
- Working with LINQ Expression trees is harder than using F# quotations, so choosing between this approach and quotations is tricky.
- F# Compiler Service gives you direct access to the compiler, but the best documented API is to compile strings (still, this might be a better choice, because it generates faster code).

Comment: Thanks. So it sounds like *how* I compile them is going to have an effect and `typed vs untyped` not at all really. The two libraries I have been looking at are: (1) FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator (uses LINQ expression trees) which gives better performance than the built-in LINQ compiler and (2) QuotationCompiler which uses an old version of FSharp.Compiler.Services - seems like this one would be best in the long-term then...?